# What case does 'plus' take?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, grammar-choice, declension, case

I don't have any information about what case to use with 'plus' (or 'magis'). In dictionaries usually only prepositions take some case, and it is showed in parentheses.

In my language, 'more' takes the genitive case. What does Latin do?

Comment: What is your native language?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it easier to understand. Regarding your "P.S." I suggest you ask a separate question!

Answer (score 3):

As Cerberus points out, *plus* is an adjective and has therefore the gender and number and case of the main word.
There is also the corresponding adverb *plus*, which could be seen as the neuter accusative of the adjective.
The word *magis* is also an adverb, [but not synonymous with *plus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2228/79).
I assume your question concerns the adverbial usage, but do bear in mind that the adjective one is possible as well.
If you want to learn about the differences of the two uses, please ask a separate new question.

The adverb *plus* means "more" or "in greater amount" (but not "to greater extent").
If you want to specify what you have more of, you use the **genitive**.
For example, "more money" would be *plus pecuniae*.
The partitive genitive has many uses, so the use with *plus* should not be seen as a special case.

An adverb can behave much like a preposition, but the important difference is that an adverb can be used alone.
You can simply cry *plus!* when you are hungry and want more food, just like you could demand "more!" in English.

Comment: Not a special case, just a case. :)

Comment: @CMonsour This has indeed been an interesting case study.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: To cry "More!", in English, might not be appreciated. Reminiscent of "Give!"; the French "Donne!". Such imperatives could generate aggression. Theory: the more violent the societies, the more elaborate are the codes of manners.

Comment: @tony Indeed, but the parallel I gave was more grammatical than cultural. In English you would generally at least add "please", depending on context. I was careful not to make a claim about manners in either language.

Answer (score 3):

The usage of *plus* and other forms like *plures, plura* seems to be a little complicated and depend on the grammatical number.

### *Plus* can be used as a singular noun or an adverb

The form *plus* looks like a singular neuter adjective in the nominative/accusative case.

However, what I've read is that this word in the singular is only used as an adverb (the nominative/accusative singular form of an adjective can often be used as an adverb in Latin), or as a noun (or "substantive").

If I understand correctly, the singular form *plus* wasn't used as an attributive adjective along with a neuter noun in the nominative/accusative singular. And *plus* does not even have attested masculine or feminine forms in the singular, which seems to rule out the possibility of it being used to modify a masculine or feminine singular noun.

As Joonas Ilmavirta said, the form *plus* can be used with a partitive genitive.

It seems that the partitive genitive could be singular or in some cases plural, even though plural nouns could instead be used in an alternative construction (discussed in the next section).

The Lewis and Short entry for *multus* (which *plus* is analyzed as the comparative of) gives the following examples (among others):

Singular genitive: *pecuniae plus, plus honoris, plus auctoritatis*

Plural genitive: *plus virium, plus hostium*

### *Plures, plura* etc. can be used as an adjective

In the plural, *plus* apparently has not only the form but also the function of an adjective, with distinct masculine/feminine and neuter forms that would agree in gender and case with the plural noun that is being modified.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective *plus* means "more". If you want to say *more than*, you can either use the (often elliptical) conjunction **quam**, or an **ablative** of comparison.

> [Ego] habeo plura capita quam homines [capita habent].

> [Ego] habeo plura capita quam [ego habeo] caudas.

After *quam*, you would use the same case as the first element of the comparison, so *ego* and *homines* are both nominatives in the first sentence ("I have more heads than humans do"); in the second sentence, both *plura capita* and *caudas* are accusatives ("I have more heads than tails").

> Habeo plura capita hominibus.

You can also use a simple complement in the ablative. In that case, it is not made explicit what the ablative is compared with, but that should be determined by context. This is mostly used when the first element of the comparison is in the nominative.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is asking about the partitive genitive construction, e.g. "plus pecuniae" = "more money"

Comment: @brianpck: Hmm that is possible. The question is less than clear.