# Latin version of "non ho che un" or "je n'ai qu'un"

Tags: idiom, syntax, romance-languages

At least Italian and French have an idiomatic way to say "I have only one friend":

- Non ho che un amico.
- Je n'ai qu'un ami.

Finnish has the same thing: "Minulla ei ole kuin yksi ystävä."
I can't think of a parallel way to phrase it in English.
("I have but one friend" is perhaps closest.)
Is there something comparable in Latin?

I can express the same though in Latin easily enough: *unum solum amicum habeo* or similarly with possessive dative.
But this is structurally quite different, and I am specifically after the structure.
Is there something like *non habeo quam unum amicum*, which corresponds quite literally to the three ones given above?
(If you add a *plus* before *quam*, the syntax seems to work out, but I don't know if the Romance versions used to have such a word.)

**What would be the closest Latin equivalent to the construction in Italian and French?**
I assume a similar thing is found in many Romance languages and they descend from Latin.
The closest I can think of is *nihil habeo nisi unum amicum*, but perhaps there is something closer.

Comment: Constructions like _non plus ultra_ suggest me something like _non plus quam amicum unum habeo_. But it seems implied by your question that you are looking for somethinkg more concise, not that "regularly" grammatical, so to say?

Comment: @Rafael I am looking for the closest Latin equivalent of the Romance thing. Perhaps there is indeed no exact match. I agree that Latin seems to require *plus* (as in your *non plus quam unum amicum habeo* or my *non habeo plus quam unum amicum*), but there might be options in Latin I had considered impossible. If there's an answer "you can't get closer than that" with upvotes, I'd be happy to consider the matter settled, as it's hard to prove impossibility. Any insight into the origins of the Romance construction would be fun, too, as it would shed light on the absence in Latin.

Comment: I guess (but it is no more than a far fetched guess) the omission of the word for more is a regional thing. In Spanish the "más" is needed: you can't say *_no tengo que un amigo_.

Comment: @Rafael That Spanish requires its *plus* unlike Italian and French is good evidence that the omission is not global and thus might not trace back to Latin. (And that the whole thing could or should be seen as omission of *plus/más/più*.) I'm getting pretty convinced – and I'm glad to learn more about Spanish as I'm in the slow process of learning some basics.

Answer (score 4):

The construction at issue here seems to have its origin in Late Latin. According to Moignet (1973: 50), one has to consider Fr. *ne que* "come remontant au latin tardif *non...quam*, représentant *non aliud quam* influencé par *non...nisi*". It seems then that *non quam* is a **crossing** of these two constructions. Unfortunately, as acknowledged by this author, this is just a hypothesis since the construction at issue (*non quam*) is not attested in Latin. Cf. also the unattested construction *nihil... quam* as an interference between the attested ones *nihil aliud quam* and *nihil nisi*. For related data and further dicussion, see [**Moignet (1973: 49-50)**](https://books.google.es/books?id=GXq5Hi-ENfgC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=Les%20signes%20de%20l%27exception%20dans%20l%27histoire%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%20%22nihil%20aliud%20quam%22&source=bl&ots=ww656aOSc4&sig=ACfU3U1QqyCLT7U_J6PA84hm_E5VOlADAQ&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM4pCG-JPrAhUeAWMBHUi8AK4Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Les%20signes%20de%20l%27exception%20dans%20l%27histoire%20du%20fran%C3%A7ais%20%22nihil%20aliud%20quam%22&f=false).

SOURCE: Moignet, Gérard (1973). *Les signes de l'exception dans l'histoire du français.* Genève: Droz.

---

The construction at issue could be said to have its origin in the omission of *plus* in the construction *non plus quam* (cf. It. *Non ho che un amico* or Fr. *Je n'ai qu'un ami*; cf. It. *più* and Fr. *plus*). However, following [Löfstedt's (1936: 23-28)](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/20442) studies on the syntax of *quam* in Late Latin, [**Moignet (1973: 49)**](https://books.google.es/books?id=GXq5Hi-ENfgC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=disparition%20du%20magis%20%22non%20magis%20quam%22&source=bl&ots=ww656aRLd1&sig=ACfU3U0NU6v0HaEbnqxEQjyW1gouexoBgg&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQwZzSgJTrAhWSxoUKHY4gBx4Q6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=disparition%20du%20magis%20%22non%20magis%20quam%22&f=false) points out that this cannot be a valid hypothesis since it seems that in Late Latin the first correlative element of the comparative clause is not necessary.

Still, in spite of the compelling data offered by [**Moignet (1973: 49)**](https://books.google.es/books?id=GXq5Hi-ENfgC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=disparition%20du%20magis%20%22non%20magis%20quam%22&source=bl&ots=ww656aRLd1&sig=ACfU3U0NU6v0HaEbnqxEQjyW1gouexoBgg&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQwZzSgJTrAhWSxoUKHY4gBx4Q6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=disparition%20du%20magis%20%22non%20magis%20quam%22&f=false) (see the data on the top of this page), note that, unlike what happens in Italian and French, the presence of *magis* in the construction *non magis quam* is compulsory in Romance languages like Spanish or Catalan: cf. Rafael's comment above on Sp. *no tengo *(más) que un amigo* or Cat., *no tinc *(més) que un amic*. Same in Portuguese, I think. So it could be the case that the different nature of the comparative adverb (*plus* vs. *magis*) could be relevant in solving this puzzle. Importantly, note that the proposal put forward by Moignet does not explain why the construction at issue here is not found in Spanish/Catalan/Portuguese. So the proposal based on the omission of the first element of the cp. clause (*plus*) is not to be discarded. What I don't know is why this omission was possible in the case of *plus* but not in the case of *magis*. For further interesting discussion on these two adverbs, please see this [post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/what-is-the-difference-between-plus-and-magis)

NB: unlike Contemporary Catalan, Old Catalan has the cp. adverb *plus* (cf. O. Cat. *pus*). It would be nice to know if the Italian/French construction at issue here was also possible in Old Catalan. Note that the prediction from my present post is that it could be well-formed.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting! I should add though that I don't think *magis* works here in Latin; [*plus* seems much more appropriate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2228/79) although words like *más* seem to come from it.

Comment: @MItomino: Doesn't "non" link with "habeo" = "I don't have"? Why "non...quam"? For me the problem was "plus...quam". Initially assuming this to be one-word-written-as-two c/f "prius" & "quam" = "priusquam" = "before". Single-word "plusquam" does not appear to exist (Ox., L & S., Wiki). When "quam" = "than", it's usually comparing nouns in the same case e.g. "puella tristior est quam puer". Arguing with Joonas, about "solum", I was still researching this. If there is a problem between "non" & "quam", what about "neque" & "quam"?

Comment: @Mitomino: Caeser: Gallic Wars 1. 53: "...neque prius fugere destiterunt quam ad flumen Rhenum," = "...they did not abandon to flight until they had reached the Rhine,". Years ago, before LSE., I had tried to translate "prius" & "quam" as separate words?!

Comment: @Mitomino: Changing the subject: on CHAT we've been discussing Pinkster's book, from which yourself has quoted, in earlier Qs. How good is this, compared with (A & G)? Is it worth the prohibitive price?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta You’re right, Joonas. I’m afraid I adopted an “Hispanicocentric” perspective in my first answer or, more probably, I was (mis)led by the following words by Moignet (1973: 49): “(…) en latin tardif,  _quam_ peut à lui seul suggérer l’idée de comparaison. Il est donc inutile de supposer la disparition  du _magis_ de _non magis quam_".  Now I think it is not the «disappearance» of _magis_ but rather that of _plus_ (pace Moignet) what can be relevant. As noted in my new edit, this could account for why the construction at issue is found in It./Fr. but not in Sp./Cat./Port.

Comment: @Mitomino It is quite peculiar if the omission of the adverb depends on whether it comes from *plus* or *magis*, but so far we do indeed have a strong correlation. If we really want to test this, I think a larger sample of Romance languages is needed and the histories, if known, of these expressions should be checked. (And there is also the possibility of later parallelisms between Romance languages, adding or removing adverbs and thus obfuscating data.) I am interested, but it seems to go way beyond what is reasonable to expect from an answer here, let alone a comment.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes, I agree with you. It is also the case that I only consulted Moignet's (1973) work. Probably, there are more recent works that could be (more) useful in disentangling this conundrum. In case I have new info, I'll let you know.

Comment: @tony I'm afraid you've raised too many questions to discuss in the comments section. As for your last general question, Pinkster (2015) is not to be compared with A&G. Rather his aim is to update (and replace) the excellent work by Kühner&Stegmann (1912). For those of us who have some difficulties in reading German, Pinkster (2015) is an excellent source. Note that Pinkster (2015) is just the **first** volume (simple clause). The 2nd volume devoted to complex clause will appear soon. It's (too) expensive, you're right, but, if you like Latin syntax, is after all a (very) good investment.

Comment: @tony Thanks for your comments. I've revised my answer. As for the status of _quam_, note that Moignet's crucial point is that, unlike in Classical Latin, "in Late Latin _quam_ can suggest the idea of comparison **by itself**". So according to him, there is no need to claim that there is an omitted _plus_ in Late Latin (NB: in Classical Latin this omission is impossible) to account for the It. and Fr. data. However, my surmise is that this omission is needed to account for the contrast between Italian/French, which have this construction, vs. Spanish/Catalan/Portuguese, which don't have it.

Answer (score 2):

The closest Latin equivalent seems to be:

> Non habeo plus quam unum amicum.

What seems to have happened is that in Italian and French you can drop the *plus*.
But you cannot drop the word in Spanish; you have to say *yo no tengo más que un amigo*.
It is not a global Romance phenomenon, and need not go all the way to Latin.
My guess is therefore that the construction mentioned in the question eroded from the Latin construction with *plus*.

The other options seem to go in a somewhat different directions.
If you have nothing at all apart from that one friend, you can say:

> Nihil habeo nisi unum amicum.

I think the most natural way to express the thought in Latin is to use a different approach, simply using *solus* to emphasize that there is only one:

> Unum solum amicum habeo.

(This answer is based on the comments so far. Feel free to post other thoughts as separate answers!)

Comment: [Comments moved to chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conversation/comments-on-https-latin-stackexchange-com-q-14302-79)

Answer (score 2):

Researching on tony's answer, I searched for **plus unum** in Perseus. Here's what I found:

> **etiam quia plus [p. 33] quam unum ex patriciis creari non licebat** ([Liv 39 32](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0174:book=39:chapter=32&highlight=plus%20unum%2C)) / *Only one consul could be a patrician* (Roberts, 1912)

> **nec umquam plus unum patiuntur melioremque pugna quaerunt** ([Sen. Cl. 1.19](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2007.01.0015:book=1:chapter=19&highlight=plus%20unum%2C)) /  *they never endure to have more than one king at a time, and find out which is the better by making them fight with one another* ([Stewart, 1900](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Of_Clemency/Book_I#XIX.))

> **non potest habere plus uno, de quo pronuntietur** [...] **si mihi plus quam unum dicere non liceret** ([Quint. Inst. 3 6](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2007.01.0059:book=3:chapter=6&highlight=plus%20unum%2C)) / *cannot have more than one point on which a decision has to be given* [...] *if I were confined to one single line of argument* ([Butler, c. 1920](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Quintilian/Institutio_Oratoria/home.html))

There were [two more results](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3AGreco-Roman&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3AArabic&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3AGermanic&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3Acwar&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3ARenaissance&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3ARichTimes&collections=Perseus%3Acollection%3APDILL&all_words=&phrase=plus%20unum&any_words=&exclude_words=&search=Search) by Seneca and Columella, but I think the point is made that, as tony said, **quam** may be omitted, but it was actually used as well. (Both alternatives were even used by the same author in the same paragraph).

So, a possible translation of the requested sentence, following a word order that kind of makes more sense to me now, would be:

> **plus unum amicum non habeo**

Comment: It's quite interesting that Latin can drop *quam* but Italian and French can drop *plus*.

Comment: @Rafael: Your third example has "plus" & "quam" together, so the use of these two is valid. I'll have a think about "one more".

Answer (score 1):

A debate, in comments (with Joonas) on the possible tautological use of "solum" = "only", when "unum" = "the one-and-only", already; and, points raised with Mitomino concerning the (i) inappropriate use of adverb "quam" = "than" (for comparing nouns in the same case); (ii) "plus" & "quam" or "plusquam"--a word which does not appear to exist; (iii) the inappropriate use of "non...quam".

It may be that both "solum" & "quam" may be excluded in order to produce the correct answer.

Firstly, Oxford gives "plus satis" = "more than enough".

Note: "than" is understood; adverb "quam" = "than" is not required. A parallel "plus unum" = "more than one".

Secondly: Allen & Greenough p.407 Note 2(c):

"After the comparatives plus, minus, amplius, longius, without "quam", a word of measure or number, is often used with no change in its case:-

"plus septingenti capti" (Liv. xii. 12) = "more than seven hundred were taken" (nominative).

Note: the noun takes the case required by the context, without reference to the comparative, which is in a sort of apposition: "seven hundred were taken (and) more".

"plus tertia parte interfecta" (B. G. iii. 6) = "more than a third-part being slain" (ablative absolute).

"aditus in latitudinem non amplius ducentorum pedum relinquebatur" (id. ii. 29) = "an approach of not more than two hundred feet was left" (Genitive of Measure p.345[b]).

Concluding: "**non habeo plus unum amicum**." = " I do not have more than one friend."

Simplifying: "I have but one friend."

Comment: Thanks (+1)! I took the liberty to edit and emphasize the final suggestion at the end.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, but then how do you say _one more_ (honest question!)?

Comment: @Rafael You should ask that as a separate question!

Comment: @Rafael: Remember Pyrrhus of Epirus? After the Battle of Heraclea, 280BC., he is reported to have said: "si talem victoriam iterum habuero, sine exercitu domum iter faciam" = "If I win one more (another) such victory, I shall make the journey home without an army". What about "two, or three, more? The cardinal numbers would have to be deployed e.g. "tres plus quam heri" = "three more than yestersay". Unattested things on the net: "hodie te amo magis quam heri" = "Today, I love you more than yesterday.". "anno 2008 plus quam 4,500,000 exemplares vendiderant in quadraginta tres linguis" =

Comment: @Rafael: "In 2008 the sales topped 4M., in more than forty languages." (Glosbe).

Comment: @tony, yes, but **iterum** means _one more time/once more/again_, I think you cannot just use it as an adjective for, say, _one more apple_