# How do you say "One more question for you." in Latin?

Tags: syntax

So, how do you say "*One more question for you.*" in Latin? I think it would be "*Unam plurem quaestionem ad te.*", but I am not sure.

Comment: It's not exactly the same phrase, but am I the only person that immediately thought of [Columbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo)?

Comment: @Adam I took it from the Duck Song. "*One more question for you. Got any grapes?*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"One more" is an English peculiarity that does not generally translate literally into other languages, including Latin. We have to think of another way of putting it.

Now, compare for example Terence: [*Eunuchus*, 5, 8](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0088%3Aact%3D5%3Ascene%3D8):

> Unum etiam hoc vos oro, ut me in vestrum gregem recipiatis.

Based on that, we might for example say:

> Unum etiam hoc te rogare volo: Habesne uvas?

Comment: It also has the benefit of not translating the noun "question" which, innocent as it is, posses some troubles. I've heard *quaestio*, *rogatum* and I think even *rogandum*. But none really work well as far as I can tell.

Comment: I find this answer fully satisfactory, but what do you think about this alternative: “et unum quod te rogem habeo”?

Comment: @Kingshorsey Studemus ut satisfaciamus. Your alternative sounds also very good to me, but it seems to me there should be a *iam* somewhere to indicate there is *still* one last question.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel: A similar Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14365/1982, has been asked before. This may be of interest to yourself.